# Double Quotes in Solr Query

Tags: solr, lucene

I cannot find out what the double quotes in this solr query means.

The query is `q=%2B"My+helper+product"+My+helper+product`. Its a **edismax** query

%2B is For the "+" sign and the other + signs are for spaces, due to the fact that its a URI request, but I dont unserstand what are the double quotes for, and the duplication.

I am new to solr and it's quite overwhelming at first. Could you help me out please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax varies depending on which query parser you're using, but the edismax parser supports the standard lucene syntax (which is what's being used here). The edismax handler has a parameter named `qf` which tells Solr which fields it should search (i.e. which fields the query (`q`) will be run against).

The [query syntax for standard lucene queries](https://lucene.apache.org/core/2_9_4/queryparsersyntax.html) [explains that the `+` means](https://lucene.apache.org/core/2_9_4/queryparsersyntax.html#+) that the term is *required* to be present.

> The "+" or required operator requires that the term after the "+" symbol exist somewhere in a the field of a single document.
>
> To search for documents that must contain "jakarta" and may contain "lucene" use the query:
>
> `+jakarta lucene`

The quotes [wraps a sequence of words that should be found](https://lucene.apache.org/core/2_9_4/queryparsersyntax.html#Fields) - i.e. in sequence, and not just as single terms.

> You can search any field by typing the field name followed by a colon ":" and then the term you are looking for.
>
> As an example, let's assume a Lucene index contains two fields, title and text and text is the default field. If you want to find the document entitled "The Right Way" which contains the text "don't go this way", you can enter:
>
> `title:"The Right Way" AND text:go`

The other words are there to give hits where they're not in sequence, but since the first term is required, I don't think they do much more than give a higher score to documents that contain the terms many times outside of where the words occure in sequence. Those words will hit where just "product" is present, or where the content contains `product helper my`.

Comment: in the question it's mentioned, that it's a edismax query.

Comment: Ah, I missed that. The edismax parser supports the Lucene syntax, so the result should be the same.

Answer (score 2):

Basically, quotes in Solr are uses to create query which will not be breaked on spaces/delimiters.

From Solr reference:

> A phrase is a group of words surrounded by double quotes such as
>   "hello dolly"

The query from the question is saying, I want to have query "My helper product" as well as all words from this phrase separately to be searched in **qf** (query fields parameter in [eDisMax](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/the-extended-dismax-query-parser.html) query parser).